# How to get just the file name, not the full directory, with NSOpenPanel?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, nsopenpanel

This is my code:

```
NSOpenPanel  *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[panel runModal];

NSInteger count = [[panel URLs] count];

for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
   NSLog(@"%@", [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

But the output is something like `file://localhost/Volumes/....`

How can I just get the basename of the selected file (e.g Cat.jpg)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = ...;
NSString *filename = [[url path] lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: Hi, Jonathan Grynspan, How can I get startup disk (Root) name if NSURL is like file:///

Comment: If you have a new question, you should ask it as a question rather than as a comment on an existing question.

Answer (score 3):

In the case only filename, without any extension, is needed:

```
NSString *fileName = [[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```